# Include dynamic styles in erb code

Tags: ruby, haml, erb

I have a line in haml:

```
.cal-grid-day-frame{:style => ("border-right: 1px solid #888" if (today.saturday?)) }
```

What is the equivalent .erb code?

I've tried:

```
<div class="cal-grid-day-frame" style="<%= "border-right: 1px solid #888" if today.saturday? %>">
```

and

```
<div class="cal-grid-day-frame"> <% style="border-right: 1px solid #888" if today.saturday? %>
```

so this works:

```
<div class="cal-grid-day-frame" style=" <%= 'border-right: 1px solid #888' if today.saturday? %>">
```

basically I had it right the first time, but hadn't switched from double to single quotes.

Hope that helps somebody else.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code-conversion site. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: "Stack Overflow isn't a code-conversion site"

Comment: Well, then, what the @&# is it for? That's a pretty rude comment. I don't ask many questions and I always try to research online before asking. It's one lousy line of code, and I've tried a bunch of things, and they didn't work. I really don't need a lesson, just a point in the right direction. If there's a succinct resource that provides the answer I haven't found it, and I always figured the programmers were a community and were happy to write up a quick response instead of asking condescending questions.

Comment: I'm trying to help you avoid getting your question closed, which it will, because you haven't showed any effort to solve the problem. You can not like that, but that is how it will be seen by others. Stack Overflow is a *debugging* site primarily; We help people fix their coding problems with what they wrote. While you will find some answers to questions similar to yours, that isn't what the site is for. So, show us what you've tried to do, and if it doesn't work we'll be happy to help.

Comment: Fair enough...
I've tried:

`<div class="cal-grid-day-frame" style="<%= "border-right: 1px solid #888" if today.saturday? %>">`

and

`<div class="cal-grid-day-frame">
   <% style="border-right: 1px solid #888" if today.saturday? %>`

Comment: It is hardly a rude comment, but it is succinct, abrupt, perhaps.  Yet accurate.  Hopefully my edit helps ease the sting a little bit.  I brought your comment with what you have tried into your question where it really belongs.

Answer (score 1):

so this works:

```
<div class="cal-grid-day-frame" style=" <%= 'border-right: 1px solid #888' if today.saturda
```

basically I had it right the first time, but had forgotten to switch between double and single quotes.

Hope that helps somebody else.